# How to create an alert for a pod running status in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, rules, prometheus-alertmanager

I have deployed prometheus, node exporter and alert manager on kubernetes and I am trying to create an alert rule to check if any specific pod is running or not.
I am getting the metrics and right now I have created a rule in prometheus.rules files as below:

```
      - alert: utils Pod not running
        expr: sum(kube_pod_container_status_running{pod=~"utils"}) < 1
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: utils pod is not running (instance {{ $labels.pod }})
```

But is not working. Can anyone help in creating a rule for checking if any specific pod is running in cluster or not. I am new to this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try using this expression `(kube_pod_status_ready{condition="true",pod_name=~"pod-name"}==0)` this fetches the pods which are not running, if you want to get the pods running then change the value to 1

Comment: Hi @GoliNikitha Thank you for your solution. But this is not working as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can check replicaset readiness status in namespace.

```
count(kube_replicaset_status_ready_replicas{namespace="yournamespace"}) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me: kube_pod_status_ready{condition="true",pod=~".*"}==0